# Modify constraint name in ddl statement from jOOQ (3.11.7)

Tags: jooq

In MariaDB I have a table that looks as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS` (
  .. stuff ..
  UNIQUE KEY `REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_key_UN` (`rmr_key`),
  .. more stuff ..
)
```

From this, jOOQ generates:

```java
public static Index REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_KEY_UN = Internal.createIndex("REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_key_UN", ReferenceManagementRequests.REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS, new OrderField[] { ReferenceManagementRequests.REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS.RMR_KEY }, true);
```

If I than do `dslContext.ddl(schema)` it generates this:

```sql
create table REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS (
  .. stuff ..
  constraint KEY_REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_key_UN unique (rmr_key)
)
```

which results in: 
`java.sql.SQLException: Identifier name 'KEY_REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_key_UN' is too long`.

Is there a way to modify the behaviour of either the generator (have it generate a shorter constant name) or the ddl function (have it use the actual name rather than the variable name)?

**edit**

oops.. not read it carefully enough. The actual error mentions this one:

```java
public static final UniqueKey<ReferenceManagementRequestsRecord> KEY_REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_KEY_UN = Internal.createUniqueKey(ReferenceManagementRequests.REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS, "KEY_REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS_key_UN", ReferenceManagementRequests.REFERENCE_MANAGEMENT_REQUESTS.RMR_KEY);
```